# Fully custom validation error message with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails I'm trying to get an error message like "The song field can't be empty" on save. Doing the following:

```
validates_presence_of :song_rep_xyz, :message => "can't be empty"
```

... only displays "Song Rep XYW can't be empty", which is not good because the title of the field is not user friendly. How can I change the title of the field itself ? I could change the actual name of the field in the database, but I have multiple "song" fields and I do need to have specific field names.

I don't want to hack around rails' validation process and I feel there should be a way of fixing that.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

Now, the accepted way to set the humanized names and custom error messages is to [use locales](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "E-mail address"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "is required"
```

Now the humanized name *and* the presence validation message for the "email" attribute have been changed.

Validation messages can be set for a specific model+attribute, model, attribute, or globally.

Comment: Setting field names by language is great, but how does one set a custom error messages by language?

Comment: If you are using mongoid, replace activerecord: with mongoid:

Comment: @graywh: Where should questions about an answer be posted, if not in the comments? Here's the I18n guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: By the way: if you pass a symbol in for the message parameter of your validator in Rails 3.1.3, it will tell you the scope it was looking for as it won't e found, so you know exactly what to put in your locales yml.

Comment: Well, this is fine and all, but what if naively prepending the column name (no matter how human readable it is) would lead to completely f-uped grammar (especially in non-english languages)? Do I really need to use `errors.add :base, msg`? I'd like to know which column the error is about, so I can display it at the correct form field.

Comment: @panzi What language did you have in mind?  Here's some sample locales in various languages: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale (This URL is given in the generated config/locales/en.yml in a new application.)

Comment: @graywh Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't it always prepend the column name before the message? Even in English I'd like to have e.g. `The password is wrong.` or `The email address is not valid.` instead of `Password is wrong.` and `Email is not valid.`.

Comment: @panzi Ah, then you probably want to look at the implementation of ActiveModel::Errors#full_message and see section 5.2.2 of the Rails I18n guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#overview-of-other-built-in-methods-that-provide-i18n-support

Comment: Don't forget to call `errors.full_messages` to actually see the humanized name.

Comment: And if you're using MongoMapper, replace `activerecord:` with `mongo_mapper:`

Comment: How could we add validation for format : like greater_that_or_equal_to

Comment: What if the attribute is actually a **belongs_to** relation?. It ain't working if I treat it like an attribute.

Comment: where can i get the full list of keywords? e.g. for "email already taken" what should i put in place of blank field??

Comment: In Rails 6, to enable that custom format for specific models or attributes, you need to enable it by adding `config.active_model.i18n_customize_full_message = true` in `config/application.rb`
That guide helped me: https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-allows-to-override-the-activemodel-errors-full_message-format-at-the-model-level-and-at-the-attribute-level

Answer (score 72):

In your model:

```
validates_presence_of :address1, message: 'Put some address please'
```

In your view

```
<% m.errors.each do |attr, msg|  %>
 <%= msg %>
<% end %>
```

If you do instead

```
<%= attr %> <%= msg %>
```

you get this error message with the attribute name

```
address1 Put some address please
```

if you want to get the error message for one single attribute

```
<%= @model.errors[:address1] %>
```

Comment: That's not an acceptable solution. What if I want the default behaviour for all the other attributes (attr + msg)?

Comment: There you go.. you can play with those 2 things and make it work

Comment: You have to use a symbol so it will look up in your yml files, like `validates_presence_of :address1, :message => :put_some_address_please `

Comment: This is not acceptable, as the field name gets included

Comment: I think that I have improved this answer to be acceptable, [please check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310995/17342313).

Answer (score 69):

Try this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |user|
    user.errors.add_to_base("Country can't be blank") if user.country_iso.blank?
  end
end
```

I found this [here](http://lindsaar.net/2008/4/23/tip-14-custom-error-messages-in-validations).

Update for Rails 3 to 6:

```
validate do |user|
  user.errors.add(:base, "Country can't be blank") if user.country_iso.blank?
end
```

Here is another way to do it.
What you do is define a human_attribute_name method on the model class. The method is passed the column name as a string and returns the string to use in validation messages.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :email => "E-mail address"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

The above code is from [here](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/12/change-displayed-column-name-in-rails-validation-messages)

Comment: The problem is that my field is called :song_rep_xyz (well, something complicated), which is not user friendly

Comment: for Rails 3, "def self.human_attribute_name(attr)" needs to be changed into "def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})", otherwise it returns an error

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed something that worked for Rails 2. (Yes, poor me... :)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, there's a way to do this without the plugin!
But it is not as clean and elegant as using the mentioned plugin. Here it is.

Assuming it's Rails 3 (I don't know if it's different in previous versions),

keep this in your model:

```
validates_presence_of :song_rep_xyz, :message => "can't be empty"
```

and in the view, instead of leaving

```
@instance.errors.full_messages
```

as it would be when we use the scaffold generator, put:

```
@instance.errors.first[1]
```

And you will get just the message you specified in the model, without the attribute name.

Explanation:

```
#returns an hash of messages, one element foreach field error, in this particular case would be just one element in the hash:
@instance.errors  # => {:song_rep_xyz=>"can't be empty"}

#this returns the first element of the hash as an array like [:key,"value"]
@instance.errors.first # => [:song_rep_xyz, "can't be empty"]

#by doing the following, you are telling ruby to take just the second element of that array, which is the message.
@instance.errors.first[1]
```

So far we are just displaying only one message, always for the first error. If you wanna display all errors you can loop in the hash and show the values.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Lovely. I was looking for getting a one-liner message for my API app and you have shown me how to manipulate the errors class. TY

Answer (score 17):

Rails3 Code with fully localized messages:

In the model user.rb define the validation

```
validates :email, :presence => true
```

In config/locales/en.yml

```
en:  
  activerecord:
    models: 
      user: "Customer"
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Email address"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "cannot be empty"
```

Answer (score 16):

In the custom validation method use:

`errors.add(:base, "Custom error message")`

as add_to_base has been deprecated.

`errors.add_to_base("Custom error message")`

Answer (score 14):

One solution might be to change the i18n default error format:

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Default is `format: %{attribute} %{message}`

Answer (score 13):

Related to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2859275/365218) and [another answer down the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809011/365218):

I'm confirming that [nanamkim's fork of custom-err-msg](https://github.com/nanamkim/custom-err-msg) works with Rails 5, and with the locale setup.

You just need to start the locale message with a caret and it shouldn't display the attribute name in the message.

A model defined as:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

with the following `en.yml`:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        item:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "^You can't create an item without a name."
```

`item.errors.full_messages` will display:

```
You can't create an item without a name
```

instead of the usual `Name You can't create an item without a name`

Answer (score 12):

I recommend installing the [custom_error_message gem](https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg) (or as a [plugin](http://github.com/gumayunov/custom-err-msg/tree/master)) originally written by David Easley

It lets you do stuff like:

```
validates_presence_of :non_friendly_field_name, :message => "^Friendly field name is blank"
```

Comment: I have used this plugin in the past with great success though it does not appear to be regularly maintained anymore.

Comment: you can alse install it as a gem for rails 3. just add `gem "custom_error_message" ` to your Gemfile - see [github](https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg) for more details

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Comment: @DickieBoy I confirm that nanamkim's fork (https://github.com/nanamkim/custom-err-msg) works with Rails 5. It actually plays nice with the accepted answer. I'll write this up as a separate answer.

Comment: @Rystraum For the life of me I can't remember the usecase around this, but thanks for the reply! I'll be sure to remember it for the future.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way:

If you use this template:

```
<% if @thing.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @thing.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

You can write you own custom message like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :custom_validation_method_with_message

  def custom_validation_method_with_message
    if some_model_attribute.blank?
      errors.add(:_, "My custom message")
    end
  end
```

This way, because of the underscore, the full message becomes " My custom message", but the extra space in the beginning is unnoticeable. If you really don't want that extra space at the beginning just add the `.lstrip` method.

```
<% if @thing.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @thing.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message.lstrip %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

The String.lstrip method will get rid of the extra space created by ':_' and will leave any other error messages unchanged.

Or even better, use the first word of your custom message as the key:

```
  def custom_validation_method_with_message
    if some_model_attribute.blank?
      errors.add(:my, "custom message")
    end
  end
```

Now the full message will be "My custom message" with no extra space.

If you want the full message to start with a word capitalized like "URL can't be blank" it cannot be done. Instead try adding some other word as the key:

```
  def custom_validation_method_with_message
    if some_model_attribute.blank?
      errors.add(:the, "URL can't be blank")
    end
  end
```

Now the full message will be "The URL can't be blank"

Comment: ooo, you can even do `errors.add(:_, 'foobar')` and get ' foobar' as the message

Comment: Good approach, I build my own implementation based on the examples here. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Just do it the normal way:

```
validates_presence_of :email, :message => "Email is required."
```

But display it like this instead

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <% @user.errors.messages.each do |message| %>
    <div class="message"><%= message.last.last.html_safe %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Returns

```
"Email is required."
```

The localization method is definitely the "proper" way to do this, but if you're doing a little, non-global project and want to just get going fast - this is definitely easier than file hopping.

I like it for the ability to put the field name somewhere other than the beginning of the string:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => "There is already an account with that email."
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code that can be useful for you in case you still need it: 
My model:

```
validates :director, acceptance: {message: "^Please confirm that you are a director of the company."}, on: :create, if: :is_director?
```

Then I have created a helper to show messages:

```
module ErrorHelper
  def error_messages!
    return "" unless error_messages?
    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg|
       if msg.present? && !msg.index("^").nil?
         content_tag(:p, msg.slice((msg.index("^")+1)..-1))
       else
         content_tag(:p, msg)
       end
    }.join

    html = <<-HTML
      <div class="general-error alert show">
        #{messages}
      </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end

  def error_messages?
    !resource.errors.empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for helping handle the case of checkbox acceptance messages ... I wonder if there's a way to do it without the custom error helper that examines the messages looking for the "^" string?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list them all in a nice list but without using the cruddy non human friendly name, you can do this...

```
object.errors.each do |attr,message|
  puts "<li>"+message+"</li>"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view

```
object.errors.each do |attr,msg|
  if msg.is_a? String
    if attr == :base
      content_tag :li, msg
    elsif msg[0] == "^"
      content_tag :li, msg[1..-1]
    else
      content_tag :li, "#{object.class.human_attribute_name(attr)} #{msg}"
    end
  end
end
```

When you want to override the error message without the attribute name, simply prepend the message with ^ like so:

```
validates :last_name,
  uniqueness: {
    scope: [:first_name, :course_id, :user_id],
    case_sensitive: false,
    message: "^This student has already been registered."
  }
```

Comment: does not work with rails 5.1 / ruby  2.4 ? getting the model name in that scope

Comment: @Ben Works for me on Rails 5.1.2, Ruby 2.4.1p111. Can you share your code?

Comment: i guess i had to look further, you can check the code and his answer there https://stackoverflow.com/q/45128434/102133

Answer (score 0):

I tried following, worked for me :)

1 job.rb

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :title, 
              :presence => true, 
              :length => { :minimum => 5, :message => "Must be at least 5 characters"}
end
```

2 jobs_controller.rb

```
def create
      @job = Job.create(job_params)
      if @job.valid?
        redirect_to jobs_path
      else
        render new_job_path
      end     
    end
```

3 _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
  <% if @job.errors.any? %>
    <h2>Errors</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @job.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>  
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, size: '60x6' %>

  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> A unique approach I haven't seen anyone mention!

The only way I was able to get all the customisation I wanted was to use an `after_validation` callback to allow me to manipulate the error message.

1. Allow the validation message to be created as normal, you don't need to try and change it in the validation helper.
2. create an `after_validation` callback that will replace that validation message in the back-end before it gets to the view.
3. In the `after_validation` method you can do anything you want with the validation message, just like a normal string! You can even use dynamic values and insert them into the validation message.

---

```
#this could be any validation
validates_presence_of :song_rep_xyz, :message => "whatever you want - who cares - we will replace you later"

after_validation :replace_validation_message

def replace_validation_message
    custom_value = #any value you would like
    errors.messages[:name_of_the_attribute] = ["^This is the replacement message where 
    you can now add your own dynamic values!!! #{custom_value}"]
end
```

The after_validation method will have far greater scope than the built in rails validation helper, so you will be able to access the object you are validating like you are trying to do with object.file_name. Which does not work in the validation helper where you are trying to call it.

Note: we use the `^` to get rid of the attribute name at the beginning of the validation as @Rystraum pointed out referencing this [gem](https://github.com/nanamkim/custom-err-msg)

Answer (score 0):

graywh's answer is the best if it actually locales different in displaying the field name. In the case of a dynamic field name (based on other fields to display), I would do something like this

```
<% object.errors.each do |attr, msg| %>
<li>
  <% case attr.to_sym %>
  <% when :song_rep_xyz %>
    <%= #display error how you want here %>
  <% else %>
    <%= object.errors.full_message(attr, msg) %>
  <% end %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

the full_message method on the else is what rails use inside of full_messages method, so it will give out the normal Rails errors for other cases (Rails 3.2 and up)

Answer (score 0):

**Upgraded** [@Federico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570415/17342313) to be **universal** for all field errors.

In your `controller.rb`:

```rb
flash[:alert] = @model.errors.messages.values 
# [["field1_err1", "field1_err2"], ["field2_err1"], ["field3_err1"]]
```

`messages` method "returns a Hash of attributes with an array of their error messages" as in [rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-messages).

Then, to display those errors in a form:

```
<% flash.each do |type, type_arr| %>
  <% type_arr.each do |msg| %>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <%= msg.to_sentence %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```