# How to remove Field Names in validates_presence_of on rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

How to remove Field Name in validates_presence_of on rails Model for the following coding

```
validates_presence_of :address, :attributes => true, :discard_if => :invalid?, :on => :save, :message=> "Invalid Address"
```

and the Output is

```
Address Invalid address
```

and I don't want Address field in this validation

Please Help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the answer you're looking for:

[Fully custom validation error message with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails)

Answer (score 2):

The standard error format is `"%{attribute} %{message}"`.  If you don't want attribute names included in messages, you can change `errors.format` in your locale.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  errors:
    format: '%{message}'
```

AFAIK, you can't do this for a single attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same question and stops on:

```
*instance.errors.add*
```

for exmpl,

```
question.errors.add("Answer","can't be blank") if self.body.blank?
```

There is *errors.add_to_base*, but just *add* is working more comfortably, for my opinion.

Comment: and after it you can do such things: