# custom error message for valid numericality of in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I wanted to have custom error messages for my field names.  I stumbled upon another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails)

So I added something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |prod|
    prod.errors.add_to_base("Product price can't be blank") if prod.prod_price.blank?
  end
end
```

But I also want to check the numericality of prod_price.  If I just add 
`validate_numericality_of :prod_price` and product price is empty then both the error messages show up (empty and is not a number).

How can I just have 'is not a number' error message show up only when product price is NOT empty?

I tried doing

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |prod|
    prod.errors.add_to_base("Product price can't be blank") if prod.prod_price.blank?
    if !prod.prod_price.blank?
       prod.errors.add_to_base("Product price must be a number") if prod.prod_price.<whatdo i put here>
    end
  end
end
```

Also, How can I have a custom message for 'is not a number'.  I want to hide showing my column name to the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have custom messages without writing your own validate method. Just add `:message`:

`validates_presence_of :prod_price, :message => "Product price can't be blank"`

If you want to skip the numericality validation when `prod_price` is not present, add :allow_nil:

`validates_presence_of :prod_price, :message => "Product price can't be blank"`
`validates_numericality_of :prod_price, :allow_nil => true`

Then the numericality check will not run when `prod_price` is missing.

EDIT:

Wait, you don't want the field name to show up in the error message, do you? I missed that. So you'll need the custom validation after all.

EDIT #2:

Ok how about this then:

```
protected

def validate
  if prod_price.blank?
    errors.add "Product price can't be blank"
  else
    begin
      Integer(attributes_before_type_cast["prod_price"])
    rescue ArgumentError  
      errors.add "Product price must be a number"
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: yeah...should have named my column names better to avoid all this mess

Answer (score 8):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150570/21115) works, but here's a data driven way to do it using Rails' i18n:

Adding `allow_blank: true` to `validates_numericality_of` will take care of the empty problem.

Then you can use i18n to automatically translate attribute names for you (docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)).
For `prod_price` you'd just add this to `en.yml`:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      product:
        prod_price: "Product price"
```

---

Now for the *must be a number* part, we can use i18n again. From [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes):

> Active Record validation error messages can also be translated easily. Active Record gives you a couple of namespaces where you can place your message translations in order to provide different messages and translation for certain models, attributes, and/or validations.

There's a handy table of those namespaces [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation), where you can see that the *message* for a *numericality* validataion is `not_a_number`.

So now we can add that to `en.yml` thus:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        product:
          attributes:
            prod_price:
              not_a_number: "must be a number"
```

---

Now when the validation fails it'll concatenate the two, to give you: *Product price must be a number*.

Answer (score 1):

For a lot of reasons, unless you need to do something unusual, you should be attaching error messages to specific fields (it's easier to do unit tests, easier to modify errors later, you can display markers next to invalid fields if you want, etc). I think what you want to do can be accomplished with this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :name, :if => lambda{ |obj| obj.prod_price? }
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Comment: but this will show the field name in the error message. I want to move away from that. how can your code be incorporated with the custom messages I have

Comment: I encourage you to look into modifying how Rails renders field error messages (maybe ask another question about how to not prepend the humanized field name to AR error messages). Adding all errors to base is not a great design. Don't replace your car's engine because you don't like the color!

Answer (score 0):

I took this approach from the other SO question

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :email => "E-mail address"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

this way I dont have to write custom message for each field. I just change the fild name presented to the user

Answer (score 0):

```
if prod.prod_price.blank?
  prod.errors.add_to_base("Product price can't be blank") 
elsif prod.prod_price.match(/[^\d]/)
  prod.errors.add_to_base("Product price must be a number")
end
```