# How to change the normal validation behavior so to add messages to custom error keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, paperclip

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the Paperclip gem. I would like to change the normal behavior to validate and add error messages to a class object.

That is, an invalid instance of a `User` class is (the `:avatar_file_size` error is related to the Paperclip gem)

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000010166cfb8 @base=#<User id: 1, firstname: "Sample firstname", lastname: "Sample lastname", avatar_file_name: "avatar_file.jpg",
...>, @messages={:avatar_file_size=>["is too big"]}>
```

I would like to have the following output (note that the `:avatar_file_size` error-hash **key** is changed to `:avatar`):

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000010166cfb8 @base=#<User id: 1, firstname: "Sample firstname", lastname: "Sample lastname", avatar_file_name: "avatar_file.jpg",
...>, @messages={:avatar=>["is too big"]}>
```

In few words, what I would like to do is *to change the error-hash key related to the error message generated by the Paperclip gem*.

**How can I do that?**

---

Maybe it is possible to do that directly in the `validates` method present in the `User` model that at this time is:

```
validates_attachment_size :avatar,
  :less_than => 4.megabytes,
  :message   => "is too big"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply an option called `message` to override the default message. I am assuming you are using the paperclip gem's size validator.

```
validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 5.megabytes, 
                            :message => "is too big"
```

Comment: I don't want to change the validation message but the key name (from ':avatar_file_size' to ':avatar') of the array where normally the message will be inserted.

Comment: You don't write the validator on the `avatar_file_size` column ( as it is a meta column for Paperclip). You write the validation for :avatar. As I have shown above the `paperclip` gem provides this out of the box.

Comment: I think your specific problem might be addressed by the solution above. If you want to change the field name generically, then refer to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521383.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I do not want to change the error message text itself but the error-hash key during the validation process. I would like to do something better of the following in order to reach what I aim to do: `@user.errors.add(:avatar, @user.errors[:avatar_file_size].first) if @user.errors[:avatar_file_size].present?`