# How to translate model in Ruby class/module namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, localization, namespaces, internationalization

I have a model Products::Car. How can I translate its attributes?

I have already tried this:

```
activerecord: 
  models:
    products:
      car: "Автомобиль"
  attributes:
    products:
      car:
        owner: "Владелец"
```

And this:

```
activerecord: 
  models:
    products_car: "Автомобиль"
  attributes:
    products_car:
      owner: "Владелец"
```

But if I try to use Products::Car.model_name.human it still says "Car". My other translations work well, and the language is set to :ru.

Comment: Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521383/activerecord-validates-custom-field-name/2522186#2522186

Comment: @HarishShetty that answer does not help the namespace issue here at all!

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I have checked 'model_name.human' source code and found 'i18n_key' method. I have tried this:

```
irb(main):006:0> Products::Car.model_name.i18n_key
=> :"products/car"
```

Then I changed my yml file to this:

```
activerecord:    
  models:
    products/car: "Автомобиль"   
  attributes:
    products/car:
      owner: "Владелец"
```

and it works!

EDIT:

For further reference: the `i18n_key` is set in the initializer of `ActiveModel::Name` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L147

and it is simply based on

```
MyClass.name.underscore
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method for finding this. It's the singular model name after a namespace that tripped me.

Comment: Ten years and three Rails versions later and this yml syntax still works. Activemodel 6.1.3.1. here.

Answer (score 0):

As of rails 3.2.12 it seems to be converted back to this:

```
activerecord: 
  models:
    products:
      car: "Автомобиль"
  attributes:
    products:
      car:
        owner: "Владелец"
```

And `products/car: "Автомобиль"` is not working anymore

Comment: products/car is still ok in Rails 5