# removing field name from validation error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in rails 3 i don't want to show field names in error messages. Anyone know how to do that ?

```
validates_presence_of :title, :message => "no title"
```

it shows

```
Title no title
```

i want

```
no title
```

Comment: That's not duplicate.

Answer (score 34):

In your form view change your current code

```
      <%@object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
```

With this

```
      <%@object.errors.messages.values.each do |msg| %>
        <%msg.each do  |m| %>
          <li><%= m %></li>
        <%end %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a double loop:
`<% @object.errors.messages.values.flatten.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
 <% end %>`

Answer (score 24):

This worked for us (Rails 4):

```
<% resource.errors.each do |attr,msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Using Rails 4.0.2, this removed the error message text and left only the bullet.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Rails 4 (haml):

```
%ul
  - @some_object.errors.messages.each do |message|
    %li= message[1][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module ActiveModel
  class Errors
    def full_messages
      map { |attribute, message|
        message
      }
    end
  end
end
```

See also: [Change displayed column name in rails](http://henrik.nyh.se/octopress/2007/12/change-displayed-column-name-in-rails-validation-messages/#comment-711738896)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Gem

https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg

You can use a '^' character at the start of the message value. And it will  only show the characters after this.

```
 validates_presence_of :title, :message => "^no title"
```

You can use the following Gem also

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dynamic_form/1.1.4

Comment: ^ Does not work.

Comment: You have to use the gem. I am using it in my project.

Comment: @riley http://stackoverflow.com/a/40254247/365218

Comment: [dynamic form](https://rubygems.org/gems/dynamic_form/versions/1.1.4) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you change the label of the element it will effect the error message label. So if you change it to a blank string it will render just the message:

```
-# reviews/_form.html.haml
= form_for review do |form|
  = form.label :rating, (review.errors[:rating] ? "" : "Rate this Item" )
```