# How can I fully change "Password doesn't match confirmation" error message activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

yml

```
en   
  activerecord:
    errors: 
      models: 
        user:
          confirmation: "Passwords do not match"
```

but I get

> "Password Passwords do not match"

how can i get rid of "Password"?

Comment: which field you are validating? Please provide the field name. Is it `password_confirmation`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        password_confirmation: "Passwords"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password_confirmation:
              confirmation: " do not match!"
```

Comment: that will also likely change the label for the field to read 'Passwords', depending on how the form was generated. Either way, it's not the right approach.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can give is to remove the attribute from the error message (so you only get the message) - [removing field name from validation error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375407/removing-field-name-from-validation-error-message)

This is what we use in `Rails 4.0.2`:

```
<% resource.errors.each do |attr,msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is also another option.

Comment: so it's a duplicate, and should be flagged as such.