# Override validation error message for SecurePassword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fully custom validation error message with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails)

I'm playing around with Rails 3.1rc1 and think [SecurePassword](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) will be useful for me. But, I don't like the default error message, `Password digest can't be blank`. If I called `validates_presence_of :password_digest` myself I could pass `:message => "Password can't be blank"` but because it's in the framework I'm not sure how to override the message to **remove the word "digest"** which will only confuse joe user. Anyone know how to do this?

**Edit:**

Tried adding an 'overriding': `validates_presence_of` like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password

  has_secure_password
  validates_presence_of :password_digest, :message => "Password can't be blank"
end
```

But when trying to submit a blank password you just get double the errors:

**Form is invalid**

- Password digest can't be blank
- Password digest Password can't be
  blank

Answer (score 20):

I believe you can use the [Rails Internationalization API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to change this.

In your config/locales/en.yml file, add the following:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        password_digest: "Password"
```

If your model class is something other than 'user', you'll need to change that line appropriately.

Anyway, this works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work if you are using mongoid + mongodb, which doesn't (obviously) use active record, any ideas for what you would do in that scenario?

Comment: @TylerBrock Take a look at the Translator gem from Hubert Łępicki / amerbit:  https://github.com/amberbit/translator

Comment: @TylerBrock for mongoid, you can just substitute the `activerecord:` bit in the i18n file with `mongoid:`

Comment: You don't need to touch any YAML files here nor do you need `validates_presence_of :password_digest`. The password_digest will automatically be validated by `has_secure_password`. Just add `validates :password, :presence => true` and leave out the rest. That worked best for me.

Answer (score 0):

All this is doing is adding the lines

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_presence_of     :password_diges
```

t

If you add the line

```
validates_presence_of :password_digest, :message => "Password can't be blank"
```

That should work, since that is just what calling has_secure_password does.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this thinking it would override the `validates_presence_of :password_digest` in the framework...but instead just doubles the error messages (see above).

Comment: Why dont you implement https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb in your app? I just dont really see a way to overide this.