# Change error message in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to change a specific error message in devise, but I dont see it in the locales

This error occurs when a user visits an emailed confirmation link for a second time:

"Confirmation token is invalid"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on your Devise version but I can see this in my devise locales file:

```
errors:
  messages:
    already_confirmed: "was already confirmed, please try signing in"
```

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails) and the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages). They were both a huge help.