# Customise carrierwave validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, carrierwave

carrierwave is giving me this validation error:

> Image You are not allowed to upload "pages" files, allowed types: jpg,
>   jpeg, gif, png

any idea how to remove the "image" attribute bit from the beginning? it doesn't read very well.

Comment: I guess you tried that https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#i18n ?

Comment: This is not a carrierwave problem, it's a rails problem, and a pretty old one: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/196109 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails

Comment: @shioyama - That sounds like the solution, but how to do it for carrierwave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  HUMANIZED_COLUMNS = {:image => ""}

  def self.human_attribute_name(attribute)
    HUMANIZED_COLUMNS[attribute.to_sym] || super
  end

 ...

end
```

[Documentation on human_attribute_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Translation/human_attribute_name)

Alternatively, in your locales file, add:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_model:
        image: ""
```

In both cases, replace `MyModel`/`my_model` by the name of the activerecord class that you are uploading images to.