# Can I specify a default error message format for a single validator across all attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, yaml

I know you can do this:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "E-mail address"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "is required"
```

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/2859275/718050

**Question 1**
Is it possible to specify the message for `blank` across an entire model, or even sitewide, instead of going into every single `attribute`?

**Question 2**
Also, it seems that `blank` comes from `:presence` in the model, e.g.

```
validates :email, :presence => true
```

So if a `:presence => true` error translates to `blank:`, where can I find a list of these translations? How am I supposed to know what `:unique => true` turns into inside en.yml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml)

as you can see you can redefine `blank` error like this:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "can't be blank"
```

Comment: Alright! A perfectly simple, straightforward, easy answer that doesn't imply that I need to start over because I'm doing everything wrong! That almost never happens! Thanks much!