# how to override model validation messages in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model,**group_question_answer.rb**

```
class GroupQuestionAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group_question
  validates_presence_of :answer 
  validates_presence_of :answer_question    

end
```

for attribute `answer` and `answer_question` i get error message as `Group question answers answer can't be blank`
I need to show only `answer cant be blank`.i even tried adding `:message=>"cant be blank"`,but still i dont get my required message.how can i remove model name and can just arrtibute error message ....

Comment: Did you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2859275/664404)? The method is outlined [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class GroupQuestionAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :answer
  validate do |group_question_answer|
    errors.add(:base, "answer can't be blank") if group_question_answer.answer.blank?
  end
end
```

works perfectly

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
irb(main):001:0> q = GroupQuestionAnswer.create
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<GroupQuestionAnswer id: nil, answer: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> q
=> #<GroupQuestionAnswer id: nil, answer: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> q.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
irb(main):004:0> q.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fc2fb325fa8 @base=#<GroupQuestionAnswer id: nil, answer: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:base=>["answer can't be blank"]}>
irb(main):006:0> q.errors.messages
=> {:base=>["answer can't be blank"]}
```

**=> {:base=>["answer can't be blank"]}**

```
irb(main):007:0> q = GroupQuestionAnswer.create(answer: "123")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (9.0ms)  INSERT INTO "group_question_answers" ("answer", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["answer", "123"], ["created_at", Fri, 28 Dec 2012 11:01:38 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 28 Dec 2012 11:01:38 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
=> #<GroupQuestionAnswer id: 1, answer: "123", created_at: "2012-12-28 11:01:38", updated_at: "2012-12-28 11:01:38">
irb(main):008:0> q.errors.messages
=> {}
```

In my opinion validate method perfect way to fully customize rails validations and that does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: thanks Evgeniy..i tried but i am getting undefined method `add_to_base' for #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xe10ce40>

Comment: yeah sorry... I should have been checked documentation myself first :) edited answer, check again

Comment: i tried..group_question_answer.errors[:base] << "Please answer...." ..but i am getting the same error as Group question answers base Please answer....

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy for quick reply...but after implementing ur suggestion..i got usual error as Group question answers base can't be blank

Comment: i don't understand! how come you get same message? did you remove "validates_presence_of :answer" ?

Comment: Where did you get this message in console or in view?

Comment: did you remove "validates_presence_of :answer" ?

Comment: remove this also. leave only line from my example, if you want to make it work

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
validates :answer, presence: { message: '<Your message>'}
validates :answer_question, presence: { message: '<Your message>'}
```

Comment: Thanks jizak..i tried validates :answer, :presence=> { :message=> 'please answer'}.but still i am getting the same usual complete error..Group question answers answer please answer

Comment: This is due to the full_messages method. You can iterate through the validation errors like a hash `model.errors.each do |attr, message|`
EDIT: the full_messages method automatically places the attribute name in front of the error message. By iterating using each you can completely omit the attribute name or choose to place it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them in your config/locales/en.yml file

As there you can do something like this,

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      answer: answer can't be blank
```