# Rails 1 to 1 relationship migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. I have 2 existing models that I want to establish a 1 to 1 relationship.

```
class User
  has_one :info

class Info
  belongs_to :user
```

My Question is do I need to create foreign keys for each of them? My end goal is to just access info via: `@user.info`.

Comment: No, only one table needs a foreign key, but you'll need some index on the database to enforce the 1-1 relationship, see here for e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284858/828193

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter said, no you don't.  Only the `belongs_to` side needs a foreign key.  Let me point you to [the Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) for this particular issue, but more widely they're excellent resources for this type of information.

Answer (score 0):

Start with simple.

```rb
@user = User.new
@user.first_name = "john"
@user.save

info = @user.info
info.address = "Some address"
info.save

@user.reload

puts @user.info.address
```

PS: I really suggest to start with a few video tutorials and just repeat what people are doing in video