# Remove attribute from validates_uniqueness_of (Rails 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling, attributes

I have the follwing at the model:

```
validates_uniqueness_if :posicao_bastidor, :message => "my message"
```

When an error occurs, rails gives me the following message:

```
"Posicao bastidor my message"
```

I don't want 'Posicao bastidor' to appear. I want just the message.

Some clue on how to do it ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails

Comment: I know, but the question is already answered and the answers don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a leading ^ in the message, like so:

```
validates_uniqueness_if :posicao_bastidor, :message => "^ my message"
```

Comment: Sorry about that, perhaps would you care and use the following plugin https://github.com/gumayunov/custom-err-msg -- please let me know if it solved your problem. Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't solve the problema myself so I did an workaround. A little more code, but for now it fits (since its only in one place I need that).