# rails form validation empty filed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

Is there an easy way to add a form validation in a Rails app that asks: "Are you sure you want to submit this form with an empty subject?"

(I googled "are you sure" blank rails, validation empty etc. and did not find a useful answer)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a validation before the user submit, you can try something like this :

```
<%= f.submit :onclick => "show_custom_confirm()" %>

<% javascript_tag do %>
  function show_custom_confirm() {
    if ('#my_field').val() == '')
      return #{confirm_javascript_function("You'll submit with an empty field. Are you sure?")};
  }
<% end %>
```