# Show different validation message for 'same field in different form' using single model, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, validation

Here I'm using error message for sign up and sign in form using devise having single model user.rb..How can I change error message for the field email and password for different form?
In user.rb I use:

```
 validates_presence_of :full_name       
 validates_presence_of :email, :message => "enter email"
 validates_confirmation_of :password
 validates_presence_of :password, :message=> "enter password"
```

In sign up form:

```
= form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  %ul
    %li
      = f.label :full_name
      = f.text_field :full_name
    %li
    = f.label :email
      = f.email_field :email
    %li
      = f.label :password
      = f.password_field :password
    %li
      = f.label :password_confirmation
      = f.password_field :password_confirmation
    %li
      = f.label :zip
      = f.text_field :zip    
   = f.submit "Sign up", :class=> "btn btn-primary"
```

In sign in form:

```
= form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|      
  %ul
    %li
      = f.label :email
      = f.email_field :email
    %li
      = f.label :password
      = f.password_field :password
    - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      %li
        = f.check_box :remember_me
        = f.label :remember_me
  %div
    = f.submit "Log in", :class=> "btn btn-primary mt10 ml60"
```

How can I change above message for sign in form?

Answer (score 0):

Be default the sign in form will show "Invalid email or password".

That is deliberate because for sign in action such vague message is the better than specific ones, like "password too short", "email doesn't exist" etc.

I don't think it's necessary to change that to the specific ones like other normal forms.

Comment: Thanks @Billy for Your answer.I have requirement to change the message

Answer (score 0):

Consider the top answer to the question here: [Fully custom validation error message with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails)

It's a pretty flexible and scalable way of modifying error messages and field names for various model attributes and their associated validation errors