# Rails validate additional fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Using Rails 4 I have a form that submits data to a Booking model. However, the form also submits an email address and this is intended for the Guest model.

I am ok inserting data into each table on submission of the form but my problem arises when I want to validate the data.

I haven't got a clue where to begin when trying to handle this extra parameter. Should I validate the email address using the Booking model (and if so how?) or should I somehow point the email part of the form to the Guest model and validate is separately?

I really am not sure how to approach this issue and any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [validates_associated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated)?

Have something like:

```
class Booking
  has_many :guests

  validates_associated :guests
end

class Guest
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: I added this validates_associated :guest, :message => "Please enter your email address - but the error message displays with the word "Guest" at the beginning.

Comment: Try looking here @tommyd456 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails