# Rails Custom validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I realise there are many questions on this already but I can't find one with a solution to this issue.

I have a custom message set with my validation rule like this:

```
validates :grace, :inclusion => { :in => 1..7, :message => " should be between 1 and 7" }
```

and the validation error message will be

```
"Grace should be between 1 and 7"
```

but I don't want it to automatically use the name **Grace** as I want it to say **Cancellation Period** - so my question is how do I override this default behaviour?

**EDIT**

Here's my view code to display errors

```
<% if @object.errors.any? %>
  <% @object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p class="error"><%= msg %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That behaviour is down to the view rather than the model, post the code that outputs the error messages. Also, try it in the console and see what the error actually is.

Comment: added view code but surely need to manipulate the message before it gets to the view?

Comment: I believe this solution should work for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails

Comment: I spotted that earlier and didn't realise it was what I needed - thanks for that