# Rails 4 custom form validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, i'd rather not have the default error validation messages so I'm using this (until I finally get around to client side validations).

```
validates :title, presence: true, :presence => { :message => "is required." }
```

By default this gets rendered as

```
Title is required.
```

How can I remove the :title, and submit my own message like:

```
:message => "Please add a title to your collection."
```

Any help is appreciated. As always, thanks!

Comment: Check this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails)

Comment: You might want to use locales: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: Thank you both! Both answers are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the example I have in for my code, you should try out errors.add :base, "your message here"

```
validate :or_fields



def or_fields
      if self.phone.blank? && self.phone2.blank? && self.email.blank? && self.email2.blank?
        errors.add :base, "You must enter either one Phone or one Email"
      end
    end
```