# Attribute name showing on Devise Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to customize my devise error messages however the attribute name is always being included on the message.

I've already changed my en.yml file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              blank: "Error"
      full_messages:
        format: "%{message}"
```

devise_helper.rb

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      count: resource.errors.count,
                      resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
      <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
      </div>
      HTML
    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

So for example on the code above the error message that displays is 
**"Password Error"** when I only wanted to display **"Error"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `full_messages` method in the overridden `devise_error_messages!` of your devise helper. 
`full_messages` method prepends `attribute name` to the validation `error message`.

Replace

```
messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
```

with

```
messages = resource.errors.messages.map { |attr,msg| content_tag(:li, msg.join(', ')) }.join
```

See my answer for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027442/rails-error-message-displays-key-and-i-only-want-value/22027770#22027770) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Comment: Can you leave out the activerecord as well?