# undefined local variable resource in Devise 4.1 and Rails 5.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am just installing Devise 4.1 into my Rails 5.0.0.rc1 project.

In my `application.html.erb`, I have this error message helper:

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

I have overridden it with [this boilerplate helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Override-devise_error_messages!-for-views):

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" unless devise_error_messages?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      :count => resource.errors.count,
                      :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end

  def devise_error_messages?
    !resource.errors.empty?
  end

end
```

Yet when I reload my site and go to my `root_page`, I get this error:

```
NameError at /
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x007f8105dc24f8>:0x007f8105db73f0>
```

The error happens at this line in my `app/helpers/devise_helper.rb`

```
  def devise_error_messages?
    !resource.errors.empty?
  end
```

In my controllers I have added:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up Device with 5.0.0.rc1 no version would work for me other than

```
gem "devise", '~> 4.0.0.rc1'
```

try changing the gem and bundling again

**Edit and Final solution**

Helper methods usually only get called inside the controller so by going to your root i guess you go to another controller. add this to your application helper

```
def resource_name
 :user
end

def resource
 @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
 @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

Comment: Good idea, but I am still getting the same error. The version this installed was `Installing devise 4.0.3 (was 4.1.0)`. Wouldn't a later version work also? Either way, changing the gem doesn't fix this error.

Comment: I checked my bundle and yes 4.0.3 is what is working for me  however i fount this it looks like a very similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232561/attribute-name-showing-on-devise-error)

Comment: I tried that solution but it didn't work for me. The issue is on the `resource`, not the rest of the daisy-chained method.

Comment: this will probably be my last guess but i found a explanation that the helper methods usually only get called inside the controller so by going to your root i guess you go to another controller Try putting in this code into your application_helper

Comment: Yes, it seems that has gotten rid of the error. Thanks much!

Comment: No pproblem glad i could help.