# Form validation message with aliased attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm using Stripe within a model class. I have a `strike_token` attribute that I am validating presences of and creating a custom message like so:

```
validates :stripe_token, presence: { message: 'Please enter valid card info' }
```

When the form is submitted and not valid, the error message is, "Stripe token Please enter valid card info"

I don't want Stripe token in the error message. I have other validations as well that would be suited for the default, so I don't want to change the default error behavior.

It would be better if I could alias the Stripe token attribute to something like `:card_info` without actually having that as an attribute on the model.

So the message could be made to read, "Card info cannot be blank"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as given below:

Just remove the `:message` part from validation.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      model_name:
        stripe_token: ""
    errors:
      models:
        model_name:
          attributes:
            stripe_token:
              blank: "Card info cannot be blank!"
```

OR

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      model_name:
        stripe_token: "Card info"
    errors:
      models:
        model_name:
          attributes:
            stripe_token:
              blank: " cannot be blank!"
```

Replace `model_name` with your model name in small letters. Please check [Fully custom validation error message with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails?answertab=active#tab-top) for more details.

**Update**

```
# config/locales/en.yml
    en:
      activerecord:
        attributes:
          model_name:
            stripe_token: "Card info"
```

Then use,

```
validates :stripe_token, presence: { message: ' cannot be blank!' }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Changing the attribute name worked, but I would prefer to set the message on the model validation itself. Like `validates :stripe_token, presence: { message: 'cannot be blank!' }` Then I'd accept your answer

Comment: Yes, I think that might be possible. Please see the update in my answer.