# Remove prepended attribute name from full error messages for errors[:base]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We're creating a Rails form that uses the `dynamic_form` gem to display error messages. For one of the models the form interacts with, we created a custom validator:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency

  validate :new_signups_have_contact_information

  def new_signups_have_contact_information
    if agency && agency.is_new_signup?
      unless (email && email != '') || (phone && phone != '')
        errors[:base] << "Please include a phone number or email."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So far, so good. When we display these errors our view, though:

```
<%= form_for @contact do |contact_form| %>
  <%= contact_form.error_messages %>
  <%# snip %>
<% end %>
```

We get this message in the errors that are generated when the validation fails:

> Contacts base Please include a phone number or email.

**How can we remove the prepended "Contacts base" from the generated error string?**

---

We've done some research: We know that this is happening because, by default, Rails' error message system [automatically prepends attribute names to their error strings](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.18/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#errors-add). In addition, in most cases, we can [modify the English localization file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.18/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) to [remove the prepended strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails).

The official Rails guide to do so, however, does not list how to change the localization for error messages given to the `errors[:base]` array or generated using custom validations. It lists how to override the generated strings for [all of the built-in validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.18/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation), but no other errors.

So, one approach we'd be willing to use: **How do we configure `config/locales/en.yml` to remove the prepended "Contacts base" string?**

---

Another approach we researched that we would rather not use is opening up the `ActiveRecord::Errors` class and writing our own implementation of the `errors#full_messages` function. ([This blog post](http://thepugautomatic.com/2007/12/full-error-messages-without-prepended-attribute-name/) describes the technique.) This approach changes the behavior of the `ActiveRecord::Errors` class for the entire project, and we would rather use an approach that has a much more local impact. **If we can't use the lcoalization file to achieve what we want, is there a more straightforward way to do so than opening up the `ActiveRecord:Errors` class?**

---

**EDIT**

The `contact.errors` hash is:

```
$ contact.errors.to_yaml
--- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Errors
base: !ruby/ActiveRecord:Contact
  attributes:
    id:
    # snip
messages: !omap
- :base:
  - Please include a phone number or emai.
```

Comment: You have identified the correct solution with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails). Is there a problem you are having that solution does not fix?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how to configure the localization file to change the strings used for our custom validator. I'm guessing it's something like `activerecord.errors.models.contact.attributes.base.<what goes here?>` or `activerecord.errors.models.contact.attributes.<our custom validator>`. What's the part of the string I'm missing?

Comment: It may be invoking activerecord.attributes.contacts.base(incorrectly). What does your errors hash look like in it's entirety?

Comment: @BookOfGreg I edited the errors hash into my question.

Comment: I just wonder if it's reading base as an attribute. Did setting activerecord.attributes.contacts.base do anything?

Comment: Yep, that made it work! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your validator is making :base appear as an attribute, override it with this locale.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      contacts:
        base: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind various attributes of the error message can also be configured

```
# config/locals/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      contacts:
        base: ""
   errors:
     messages:
       blank: "missing"
```