# Override Error message on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to override the following error message:

```
@order.errors.full_messages
=> ["Payments source is invalid"]
```

or

```
> @order.errors.messages
=> {:"payments.source"=>["is invalid"], :store_credit_amount=>[], :gift_code=>[]}
```

`Payments source is invalid` is currently displayed, I would like to show something like:

```
Please check your credit card info.
```

Any idea how this can be achieved in a clean way?

Thanks,

Comment: This can be done in your model by setting the message on your validator or by adding a custom text to I18n (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails). Can you please post your code that does the validation?

Comment: I'm on spree and I wasn't able to find that error message inside my bundle

Comment: Might be best to replace the hash key and value