# Where do I set template for rails error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I want rails to show error message

```
Field <field name> can't be blank
```

but using standard means I get

```
<field name> Field <field name> can't be blank
```

---

Here's a minimal example reproducing the problem:

```
rails new test
cd test
rails g scaffold user name
rake db:migrate
```

Add validation to `app/models/user.rb`:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Edit `config/locale/en.yml` to be:

```js
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name: "Name"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Field %{attribute} can't be blank"
```

After this start the server

```
rails s
```

point browser to http://localhost:3000/users/new and press "Create User" button. You'll get:

[image]

Apparently, there's another template somewhere, which says something like

```
%{attribute} %{message}
```

but I can't find it in rails code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails

Comment: @aliibrahim: I saw it but alas -- it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in a standard view generated by scaffold (`views/users/_form.html.erb`) you have:

```
<% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
```

This is what returns

> Name Field Name can't be blank

Instead, you can modify the `_form` view and use `user.errors.messages`, where you get a hash with errors assigned to keys representing fields:

```
@user.errors.messages
{:name=>["Field Name can't be blank"]}
```

To get what you expect you could write for example:

```
<% @user.errors.messages.values.flatten.each do |message| %>
  <li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
```