# In RoR, how do I customize a validation error message that is set to numericality greater than zero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, numeric

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have this validation rule for my model

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :time_in_ms, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
```

I want to write a custom error message, so in my config/locales/en.yml file I included

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_object:
        name: "Name"
      my_object_time:
        time_in_ms: "Time"
    errors:
      models:
        my_object_time:
          attributes:
            time_in_ms:
              not_a_number: "This field must be a number greater than zero."
              blank: "This field must be a number greater than zero."
```

But when my object fails to validate, this custom error message is not included in my @my_object_time.errors.full_messages array .  Instead what is included is

```
Must be greater than 0
```

What is the proper rule to write in my config file so that I can customize this error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fully custom validation error message with Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize message directly in model.

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :time_in_ms, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, message: 'my customized message.'

end
```

or in your `en.yml` file you need to add message for `greater_than:`

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_object:
        name: "Name"
      my_object_time:
        time_in_ms: "Time"
    errors:
      models:
        my_object_time:
          attributes:
            time_in_ms:
              not_a_number: "This field must be a number greater than zero."
              blank: "This field must be a number greater than zero."
              greater_than: "my custom message for greater than"
```