# The address directs me to the child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got two models; film model is the parent and the review model is the child. I expect the following code to direct me back to the film interface:

```
 def create
    @film = Film.find(params[:film_id])
    @review = @film.reviews.new(review_params)
    if @review.save
    redirect_to film_path(@film)
    else
        render "films/#{@film.id}"
     end 
   end
```

It renders me back to the following address: films/22/reviews when it suppose to direct me back to the same interface (films/22)?

I want to return back to the same interface so i can post the errors the user has made?

Comment: redirect_to :back

Comment: How would I print the validation of the error?

Comment: you can get through  flash messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in else part

```
flash[:alert] = @review.errors.full_messages.join(',  ') 
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: Cheers mate, one more question; how would i change the lettering and layout of the error?

Comment: @javacoder use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails.................   Accept answer as solution by clicking tick mark and upvote if you think your problem is solved