# Comparing rspec custom ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid errors messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

Having the following in the model :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title,
    if: proc { |item| item.item_type == 'tag' },
    case_sensitive: false,
    message: I18n.t('errors.key', value: "%{value}")
```

and trying to validate in rspec with the following :

```
expect { xxx }.to raise_error(
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,
    I18n.t('errors.key', value: '...passing the title...')
)
```

Am stuck with the very close following :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid with "translated error",
got #<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: translated error>
```

The expectation awaits a value without quote, while the value sent has quote; it fails on that

I get the very same error with the default setup :

```
activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        item:
          attributes:
            title:
              taken: 'translated error'
```

The same test passes with the followings :

`expect { xxx }.to raise_error`

`expect { xxx }.to raise_error( ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid )`

So does using the default setup :

Thanks if any help on that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord adds the prefix `Validation failed:` to the error message. Try this in your test instead:

```
expect { xxx }.to raise_error(
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,
  "Validation failed: " + I18n.t('errors.key', value: '...passing the title...')
)
```

You can change this default by setting the following key in your language file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        record_invalid: "Validation failed: %{errors}"
```