# Rails validations, mixing messages and full_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-2.3, ruby-on-rails-5

For the most part, I find that Rails default error messages for most of the built-in validators work fine for me. However, I also have a few validations on some models where the default "{{attribute}} {{message}}" full_message format just doesn't make any semantic sense. I know that I can display the messages instead of the full_messages, but that would mean I have to add in my own messages to *every* built-in validation, because otherwise the attribute name would be chopped off.

Is there a way to use the default full_message format, but to directly override the full_message for just a handful of validations to use a different format or a particular string? Is there a natural way to mix the default validation messages with a few custom ones that don't start with the attribute name?

Comment: I think you're going to want to implement what's described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2859275/3741320

Comment: The `add_to_base` method mentioned in there was exactly what I needed,  except that it was deprecated and finally removed in 4.2, and I'm using Rails 5. The new syntax is apparently `errors(:base, "message")`. In other words, if you use :base as the attribute symbol, Rails will *not* add the attribute name to your message.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom messages to config/locales/en.yml

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem. I can store my messages there, but I18n still automatically prepends the attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, the `errors.add_to_base("Something is terribly wrong!")` would add an error to the base model, instead of an attribute, and in this case `full_message` returns the same thing as `message` with no prepended attribute name.

This was removed in rails 4.2, and the new way to do it is with `errors.add(:base, "Something is terribly wrong!")`.