# Trying to override ActiveRecord field and model name with Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, internationalization

I'm using Rails 5.2.1, and trying to override the names of some ActiveRecord models and fields.

I know that Rails is picking up the English locale file because when I add the following to `locales/en.yml`, my form labels are updated to the correct values:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      seller_address: "Address"
    attributes:
      seller_address:
        name: "Name"
        street1: "Street Line 1"
        postal_code: "Postal Code"
```

But when I call `@seller_address.errors.full_messages` I'm still seeing the old field and model values. For example, this:

```
Seller addresses name can't be blank

Seller addresses street1 can't be blank

Seller addresses postal code can't be blank
```

should be this:

```
Addresses Name can't be blank

Addresses Street Line 1 can't be blank

Addresses Postal Code can't be blank
```

What can I do to tell Rails to use my locale overrides for ActiveRecord validation error messages?

Comment: Did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Yep I tried that, unfortunately didn't change anything.

Comment: See if this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define i18n errors like this in your `errors.en.yml` file.

```
en:
  activerecord:
      attributes:
      errors:
        full_messages:
          format: "%{attribute} %{message}"         # You can change your error format here.
        models:
        seller_address:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: 'Addresses Name can't be blank.'
            street1:
              blank: 'Addresses Street Line 1 can't be blank.'
```

Comment: Updating my locale file to this produced the following error message: "Seller addresses street1 Addresses Street Line 1 can't be blank." I'm starting to think you can't use .full_messages with locale file based i18n.

Comment: @yakattack If you just want the message you can change the full_messages format to have just the `%{message}`.