# Why does updating Rails from '6.0.4.8' to '6.1.6.1' break "^" string functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, error-messaging

I'm upgrading my project from Rails '6.0.4.8' to '6.1.6.1'. Doing so breaks a lot of my rspec tests (as I somewhat expected). But I can't seem to figure out why I have a number of the form:

```
Failure/Error:
    expect(log.errors.full_messages).to(include('error message'))
  
    expected ["attribute name ^error message"] to include "error message"
```

Obviously with slight variations based on the type of test, but I'm not about to post all 50 of them here. From my understanding the "^" is supposed to trim the string to only contain everything following (i.e., get rid of the attribute name and keep the error message. Has this been changed in a newer version? And at any rate, this is checking for inclusion, not an exact match, so it's strange that it's failing.

Here are the packages I updated:

```
-gem 'rails', '6.0.4.8'
+gem 'rails', '6.1.6.1'

-gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 6.0'
+gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 7.0'

-  gem 'rspec-rails', '4.0.0.beta3'
+  gem 'rspec-rails', '4.1.2'

-    actioncable (6.0.4.8)
-      actionpack (= 6.0.4.8)
+    actioncable (6.1.6.1)
+      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)

-    actionmailbox (6.0.4.8)
-      actionpack (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activejob (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activerecord (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activestorage (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
+    actionmailbox (6.1.6.1)
+      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activestorage (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)

-    actionmailer (6.0.4.8)
-      actionpack (= 6.0.4.8)
-      actionview (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activejob (= 6.0.4.8)
+    actionmailer (6.1.6.1)
+      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
+      actionview (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)

-    actionpack (6.0.4.8)
-      actionview (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
-      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
+    actionpack (6.1.6.1)
+      actionview (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
+      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)

-    actiontext (6.0.4.8)
-      actionpack (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activerecord (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activestorage (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
+    actiontext (6.1.6.1)
+      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activestorage (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)

-    actionview (6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
+    actionview (6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)

-    activejob (6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
+    activejob (6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)

-    activemodel (6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
-    activerecord (6.0.4.8)
-      activemodel (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
-    activestorage (6.0.4.8)
-      actionpack (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activejob (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activerecord (= 6.0.4.8)
-      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
-    activesupport (6.0.4.8)
+    activemodel (6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
+    activerecord (6.1.6.1)
+      activemodel (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
+    activestorage (6.1.6.1)
+      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
+      marcel (~> 1.0)
+      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
+    activesupport (6.1.6.1)

-      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
-      minitest (~> 5.1)
-      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
-      zeitwerk (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
-    acts-as-taggable-on (6.5.0)
-      activerecord (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
+      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
+      minitest (>= 5.1)
+      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
+      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
+    acts-as-taggable-on (7.0.0)
+      activerecord (>= 5.0, < 6.2)

-    autoprefixer-rails (10.4.2.0)
+    autoprefixer-rails (10.4.7.0)

-    bcrypt (3.1.17)
+    bcrypt (3.1.18)

-    bootsnap (1.11.1)
+    bootsnap (1.13.0)

-    capybara (3.36.0)
+    capybara (3.37.1)

-    erubi (1.10.0)
-    excon (0.92.3)
+    erubi (1.11.0)
+    excon (0.92.4)

-    faker (2.20.0)
+    faker (2.22.0)

-    faraday (1.10.0)
-      faraday-em_http (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-em_synchrony (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-excon (~> 1.1)
-      faraday-httpclient (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-multipart (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-net_http (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-net_http_persistent (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-patron (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-rack (~> 1.0)
-      faraday-retry (~> 1.0)
+    faraday (2.4.0)
+      faraday-net_http (~> 2.0)

-    faraday-em_http (1.0.0)
-    faraday-em_synchrony (1.0.0)
-    faraday-excon (1.1.0)
-    faraday-httpclient (1.0.1)
-    faraday-multipart (1.0.3)
-      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
-    faraday-net_http (1.0.1)
-    faraday-net_http_persistent (1.2.0)
-    faraday-patron (1.0.0)
-    faraday-rack (1.0.0)
-    faraday-retry (1.0.3)
+    faraday-net_http (2.1.0)
+    faraday-retry (2.0.0)
+      faraday (~> 2.0)

-    fog-google (1.18.0)
+    fog-google (1.19.0)

-    gapic-common (0.8.0)
-      faraday (~> 1.3)
+    gapic-common (0.11.1)
+      faraday (>= 1.9, < 3.a)
+      faraday-retry (>= 1.0, < 3.a)

-      googleapis-common-protos (>= 1.3.11, < 2.a)
-      googleapis-common-protos-types (>= 1.0.6, < 2.a)
-      googleauth (>= 0.17.0, < 2.a)
+      googleapis-common-protos (>= 1.3.12, < 2.a)
+      googleapis-common-protos-types (>= 1.3.1, < 2.a)
+      googleauth (~> 1.0)

-    globalize (6.1.0)
+    globalize (6.2.1)

-    google-apis-compute_v1 (0.34.0)
-      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
-    google-apis-core (0.4.2)
+    google-apis-compute_v1 (0.45.0)
+      google-apis-core (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-apis-core (0.7.0)

-    google-apis-dns_v1 (0.19.0)
-      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
-    google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 (0.10.0)
-      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
-    google-apis-monitoring_v3 (0.24.0)
-      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
-    google-apis-pubsub_v1 (0.17.0)
-      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
-    google-apis-sqladmin_v1beta4 (0.27.0)
-      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
-    google-apis-storage_v1 (0.13.0)
-      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
+    google-apis-dns_v1 (0.23.0)
+      google-apis-core (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 (0.13.0)
+      google-apis-core (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-apis-monitoring_v3 (0.32.0)
+      google-apis-core (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-apis-pubsub_v1 (0.24.0)
+      google-apis-core (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-apis-sqladmin_v1beta4 (0.32.0)
+      google-apis-core (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-apis-storage_v1 (0.17.0)
+      google-apis-core (>= 0.7, < 2.a)

-    google-cloud-error_reporting-v1beta1 (0.4.5)
-      gapic-common (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-cloud-error_reporting-v1beta1 (0.5.0)
+      gapic-common (>= 0.10, < 2.a)

-    google-cloud-functions (1.1.3)
+    google-cloud-functions (1.2.0)

-    google-cloud-functions-v1 (0.6.0)
-      gapic-common (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-cloud-functions-v1 (0.8.0)
+      gapic-common (>= 0.10, < 2.a)

-    google-cloud-logging (2.2.2)
+    google-cloud-logging (2.3.1)

-    google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.7.0)
-      gapic-common (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.8.1)
+      gapic-common (>= 0.10, < 2.a)

-    google-cloud-storage (1.36.2)
+    google-cloud-storage (1.38.0)

-      google-apis-storage_v1 (~> 0.1)
+      google-apis-storage_v1 (~> 0.17.0)

-    google-cloud-trace (0.41.3)
+    google-cloud-trace (0.42.1)

-    google-cloud-trace-v1 (0.3.5)
-      gapic-common (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-cloud-trace-v1 (0.4.0)
+      gapic-common (>= 0.10, < 2.a)

-    google-cloud-trace-v2 (0.3.5)
-      gapic-common (>= 0.7, < 2.a)
+    google-cloud-trace-v2 (0.4.0)
+      gapic-common (>= 0.10, < 2.a)

-    google-protobuf (3.20.1)
+    google-protobuf (3.21.4)

-    googleapis-common-protos-types (1.3.1)
+    googleapis-common-protos-types (1.3.2)

-    googleauth (1.1.3)
+    googleauth (1.2.0)

-    grpc (1.45.0)
+    grpc (1.48.0)

-    grpc-google-iam-v1 (1.1.0)
+    grpc-google-iam-v1 (1.1.1)

-    http-cookie (1.0.4)
+    http-cookie (1.0.5)

-    i18n (1.10.0)
+    i18n (1.12.0)

-    jquery-rails (4.4.0)
+    jquery-rails (4.5.0)

-    json (2.6.1)
-    jwt (2.3.0)
+    json (2.6.2)
+    jwt (2.4.1)

-    minitest (5.15.0)
+    minitest (5.16.2)

-    momentjs-rails (2.29.1.1)
+    momentjs-rails (2.29.4.1)

-    msgpack (1.5.1)
+    msgpack (1.5.4)

-    multipart-post (2.1.1)
-    mysql2 (0.5.3)
+    mysql2 (0.5.4)

-    nokogiri (1.13.6)
+    nokogiri (1.13.8)

-    oj (3.13.11)
+    oj (3.13.19)

-    pdf-reader (2.9.2)
+    pdf-reader (2.10.0)

-    phony (2.19.11)
+    phony (2.20.0)

-    rack (2.2.3.1)
+    rack (2.2.4)

-    rack-test (1.1.0)
-      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
-    rails (6.0.4.8)
-      actioncable (= 6.0.4.8)
-      actionmailbox (= 6.0.4.8)
-      actionmailer (= 6.0.4.8)
-      actionpack (= 6.0.4.8)
-      actiontext (= 6.0.4.8)
-      actionview (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activejob (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activemodel (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activerecord (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activestorage (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
-      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
-      railties (= 6.0.4.8)
+    rack-test (2.0.2)
+      rack (>= 1.3)
+    rails (6.1.6.1)
+      actioncable (= 6.1.6.1)
+      actionmailbox (= 6.1.6.1)
+      actionmailer (= 6.1.6.1)
+      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
+      actiontext (= 6.1.6.1)
+      actionview (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activemodel (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activestorage (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
+      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
+      railties (= 6.1.6.1)

-    rails-i18n (7.0.3)
+    rails-i18n (7.0.5)

-    railties (6.0.4.8)
-      actionpack (= 6.0.4.8)
-      activesupport (= 6.0.4.8)
+    railties (6.1.6.1)
+      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
+      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)

-      rake (>= 0.8.7)
-      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
+      rake (>= 12.2)
+      thor (~> 1.0)

-    regexp_parser (2.3.1)
-    representable (3.1.1)
+    regexp_parser (2.5.0)
+    representable (3.2.0)

-    rmagick (4.2.5)
+    rmagick (4.2.6)

-    rspec-rails (4.0.0.beta3)
+    rspec-rails (4.1.2)

-      rspec-core (~> 3.8)
-      rspec-expectations (~> 3.8)
-      rspec-mocks (~> 3.8)
-      rspec-support (~> 3.8)
+      rspec-core (~> 3.10)
+      rspec-expectations (~> 3.10)
+      rspec-mocks (~> 3.10)
+      rspec-support (~> 3.10)

-    rubocop (1.28.2)
+    rubocop (1.33.0)
+      json (~> 2.3)

-      rexml
-      rubocop-ast (>= 1.17.0, < 2.0)
+      rexml (>= 3.2.5, < 4.0)
+      rubocop-ast (>= 1.19.1, < 2.0)

-    rubocop-ast (1.17.0)
+    rubocop-ast (1.19.1)

-    rubocop-performance (1.13.3)
+    rubocop-performance (1.14.3)

-    rubocop-rails (2.14.2)
+    rubocop-rails (2.15.2)

-    rubocop-rspec (2.10.0)
-      rubocop (~> 1.19)
+    rubocop-rspec (2.12.1)
+      rubocop (~> 1.31)

-    sdoc (2.3.2)
+    sdoc (2.4.0)

-    selenium-webdriver (4.1.0)
+    selenium-webdriver (4.3.0)

-      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
-    shopify_api (10.0.3)
+      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
+      websocket (~> 1.0)
+    shopify_api (11.0.1)

-    signet (0.16.1)
+    signet (0.17.0)

-      faraday (>= 0.17.5, < 3.0)
+      faraday (>= 0.17.5, < 3.a)

-    sorbet-runtime (0.5.9959)
+    sorbet-runtime (0.5.10274)

-    ssrf_filter (1.0.7)
+    ssrf_filter (1.0.8)

-    thread_safe (0.3.6)
-    tilt (2.0.10)
+    tilt (2.0.11)

-    tzinfo (1.2.10)
-      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
+    tzinfo (2.0.5)
+      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)

-    unf_ext (0.0.8.1)
-    unicode-display_width (2.1.0)
+    unf_ext (0.0.8.2)
+    unicode-display_width (2.2.0)

+    websocket (1.2.9)

-    zeitwerk (2.5.4)
+    zeitwerk (2.6.0)

-  acts-as-taggable-on (~> 6.0)
+  acts-as-taggable-on (~> 7.0)

-  rails (= 6.0.4.8)
+  rails (= 6.1.6.1)

-  rspec-rails (= 4.0.0.beta3)
+  rspec-rails (= 4.1.2)
```

Let me know if I'm missing any noob details.

Like this probably very important detail:

```
$ bundle exec ruby --version
ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-linux-musl]
```

And this:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.15.4
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.15"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
```

For good measure:

```
$ bundle exec rspec --version
RSpec 3.11
  - rspec-core 3.11.0
  - rspec-expectations 3.11.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.11.1
  - rspec-rails 4.1.2
  - rspec-support 3.11.0
```

Now feel free to tear me to shreds ;-)

Comment: And of course this affects the actual website, e.g.,
"1 error prohibited this Password from being saved:
Password ^Please select a stronger password."
should not have "Password ^" at the front.

Comment: I've been using Rails a very long time and I don't believe your understanding of the `^` inside a string is correct, at least with regards to standard Ruby and Rails. Perhaps inside your app there is an extension to the Ruby string class that uses this syntax? Also, what is the syntax `expected [....] to include "..."` is that a typo? I don't believe it ever could have worked as typed in your question.

Comment: @LesNightingill What does it mean for the syntax of an output error message string from rspec to "work?"
I do realize now that it's checking against an array with one string as opposed to the string itself.

Comment: ha I completely misunderstood your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you observed that error messages starting with a `^` omit the attribute name when calling `full_messages` has never been a default Ruby on Rails feature.

Instead, plugins like [`custom-err-msg`](https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg) or gems based on that plugin were used to add this behavior to Rails. Other options were to override Rails methods to add this functionality. See this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails) for more examples of how this was done in the past.

Since Ruby on Rails 6.1 most of those techniques do not work anymore because in Ruby on Rails 6.1 errors are not a simple hash of attribute keys and message strings anymore. This [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32313) introduced an `ActiveModel::Error` model that encapsulates error messages with Rails 6.1.

The recommended way to achieve the behavior you are looking for is to take advantage of the localization framework and override the default error message format that Rails uses when `full_messages` is called. This can be done on different levels, application wide, just for one model, or even only for one specific attribute.

For example when you want to omit the attribute name on only want to show the error message for a `Post#title` error, then add the following to your `config/locales.en.yml`:

```
# config/locales/en.yml

en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        post:
          attributes:
            title:
              format: "%{message}" # default is "#{attribute} #{message}"
```

I suggest having a look at [this blog article](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-allows-to-override-the-activemodel-errors-full_message-format-at-the-model-level-and-at-the-attribute-level) that gives tons of examples how to customize error messages depending on your needs.